# Using ggplot2 geom_bar is thare a way to subset two factors on the x axis and group pairs within them?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, subset, factors

My dataset contains levels of glottals used in speech of children and their caregivers. Factors are `Speaker` (a, amum, b, bmum ...), `Category` (child, caregiver) and `Pair` (a and amum ...).

My plot shows 22 speakers' levels of glottalisation using the following code:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Speaker, fill=Glottals, colour = Category)) + 
  geom_bar(position ="fill") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("White", "grey")) + 
  theme_minimal() + ggtitle ("Percent glottals for caregiver pairs") + ylab("Percent") + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + xlab("Speaker") + theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

with the following output:

[image]

I would like to show bars in two colours (child/caregiver) and have a space between each pair.

```
A tibble: 3,303 x 15
   Context Transcript   Pair  Speaker Ch_Gender   Age Category    ID Gender Before               Text   After   Phon         Glottals Sitcon 
   <fct>   <fct>        <fct> <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <fct>    <int> <fct>  <fct>                <fct>  <fct>   <fct>        <fct>    <fct>  
 1 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      "It's not* coming"   out    ""      coda pause   t        routine
 2 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      "I'll (inc)"         that   "out."  coda vowel   ?        routine
 3 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      "I'll (inc) that"    out.   ""      coda pause   ?        routine
 4 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      ""                   Butter ""      Intervocalic t        routine
 5 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      ""                   Butter "Flour" Intervocalic t        routine
 6 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      "Mummy there's the"  butter ""      Intervocalic t        routine
 7 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      "Mummy can you open" that?  ""      coda pause   ?        routine
 8 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      "Mummy I"            want-- ""      coda pause   ?        routine
 9 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      "I want to do the"   butter ""      Intervocalic t        routine
10 Home    David_H1.trs David David   M           3.2 Child        3 M      "I wanna do the"     fruit  ""      coda pause   ?        routine
# ... with 3,293 more rows
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#Code
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Speaker, fill=Glottals, fill = Category)) + 
geom_bar(position ="fill") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("White", "grey")) + theme_minimal() + ggtitle ("Percent glottals for caregiver pairs") + ylab("Percent") + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + xlab("Speaker") + theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code. Is it possible to have two colours (child and caregiver) and to have each pair spaced from next.

Comment: @Marj I would need to see your data. Could you please use `dput(data1)` and paste the output editing yur question?

Comment: Am new to this. How do I send my dataset?

Comment: You can use `dput(data1)` and copy the outcome, then click on edit in the low side of your question. Paste that and save changes.